# Como hacer una subconsulta async en Promise.all

Tags: javascript

como va? tengo este problema, este es mi codigo:

```
 const get = await axios.get('https://swapi.dev/api/films/1/');

 const getAxios = async (p: string) => await (await axios.get(p)).data;
    const characters = (
      await Promise.all(get.data.characters.map((i: string) => getAxios(i)))
    ).map((i) => ({
      Nombre: i['name'],
      Genero: i['gender'],
      Color_de_cabello: i['hair_color'],
      Color_de_piel: i['skin_color'],
      Estatura: i['height'],
      Link: i['homeworld'], // http://swapi.dev/api/planets/22/
      NombreDelPlanetaProveniente: getAxios(i['homeworld']),
    }));
```

Esta promesa me trae todos los actores de la api Todo bien hasta aqui, ahora bien, lo que intento hacer es traerme el nombre del planeta que esta afiliado a la api, mi intento de solucion fue esta:

```
getAxios(i['homeworld']).then((rres) => {
        console.log(rres.name);
        return rres.name;
```

Efectivamente console.log si me funciona, pero no me retorna el valor, por que pasa esto?

Comment: ¿Te regresa algún error o solo retorna _undefined_?

Comment: solo me  retorna undefined, pero con el console.log() me trae la data

Comment: En ese caso, creo que el problema está en que la respuesta de axios es una promesa por lo que no solo se puede retornar. En el primer ejemplo el uso de async/await hace posible hacer el return inmediato.